# console.log fires, but subsequent Jquery call doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
    jQuery( window ).load( function( ) {
        if ( jQuery('select#pa_form option:selected').val().length > 0 ) {
            if( ! jQuery('div.single_variation').html().length) {
                jQuery('div.single_variation').append("<span class='price'><span class='amount'>$" + jQuery("meta[itemprop=price]").attr('content') + "</span></span>");
            }
            jQuery( 'select#pa_form').change( function() {
                console.log( 'i tried' );
                jQuery('div.single_variation').html("<span class='price'><span class='amount'>$" + jQuery("meta[itemprop=price]").attr('content') + "</span></span>");
            });
        }
    });
```

The problem I'm having is that when I change the select the console.log statement of "i tried" is getting fired, but the jQuery `.html` call isn't firing.

If I throw the following into the console it works:

```
        jQuery( 'select#pa_form').change( function() {
            console.log( 'i tried' );
            jQuery('div.single_variation').html("<span class='price'><span class='amount'>$" + jQuery("meta[itemprop=price]").attr('content') + "</span></span>");
        });
```

However, if I remove that snippet from within the `jQuery( window ).load( function() {});` function nothing fires.

What am I doing wrong?

[Here's a live version of the code](http://shop-updates.marleycoffee.com/product/one-love-bags/)

Comment: Please post a working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** including your HTML.

Comment: Why did you wanna remove? Did you made sure that DOM is ready before those lines are executed?

Comment: @ShaunakD I've added a link to the page I'm working on

Comment: @NK the initial change to the `div.single_variation` is working, however it's on a change the `select#pa_form` that it's not working, but the console.log statement fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price is being shown correctly by your code, but then there is another `change` event handler being fired that is bound by the wooCommerce JS, which ultimately ends up clearing the price out again.

The easiest way to get this to work is hacky, but will do the job. Just defer the updating using `setTimeout()` with a delay of 0 to allow the other change handler to fire first, then do what you want to do afterwards. I only suggest this because I assume the wooCommerce JS is too difficult to change.

Here is one way to do that:

```
jQuery( window ).load( function( ) {
    if ( jQuery('select#pa_form option:selected').val().length > 0 ) {
        if( ! jQuery('div.single_variation').html().length) {
            addPrice('append');
        }
        jQuery( 'select#pa_form').change( function() {
            console.log( 'i tried' );
            addPrice('html');
        });
    }
});

function addPrice(method) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery('div.single_variation')[method]("<span class='price'><span class='amount'>$" + jQuery("meta[itemprop=price]").attr('content') + "</span></span>");
    }, 0);
}
```

I also made the code a little more DRY so it is easier to maintain.

#### How I found the problem

Here is how I found the problem in Chrome devtools so you can learn how to do it yourself.

1. Set a breakpoint at the line that makes the change (the one after the `console.log('i tried')` line).
2. Change the dropdown, the breakpoint gets hit.
3. Step over once (F10), look back in the browser, the price has appeared. So far, so good.
4. Resume (F8), and it disappears again.
5. Set a DOM breakpoint on the `<div id="desc_bucket">` element, the parent of the element I expect to change. Right click on it in the Elements tab, select "Break on..." and "Subtree modifications".
6. Change the dropdown again, and resume (F8) when it hits your code.
7. The next time it breaks, it will be because of the wooCommerce code, where you can explore the stacktrace to figure out what is going on.

DOM Breakpoints: handy sometimes.

Comment: That works great. You saved me a ton of time on this maintenance fun I'm having taking over from another developer.

Comment: Woo, money! Boo, other people's code. Btw, I updated my answer with how I found the problem so you can do the same trick next time by yourself.

Comment: I already ripped out the custom javascript portion of the template that was put in to target one specific product setup, but affected all products. In this situation the default price is being hidden for themeing reasons (whatever) and there's this custom div now. Thanks so much for your help. I was able to get to some badly needed performance tuning for the server/sites since they just migrated to a VPS tonight.